# Trouble accessing a values in nested hashes

Tags: perl

I'm trying to access some lists that are two-deep into a hash.  Here's my code:

```
my %english = (
    greetings => [("Hello", "What's up?")],
);

my %spanish = (
    greetings => [("Hola", "Que pasa?")],
);

my %bighash = (
    english => %english,
    spanish => %spanish,
);

print 'English greetings: ';
if (my $array = $bighash{'english'}{'greetings'}) {
    print "\n$_" for @$array
}
else {
    print 'Fail.';
}
```

However, the `if` condition always evaluates to 'false'.  Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

The expressions

```
english => %english,
spanish => %spanish,
```

are not correct as a hash value must be a scalar (such as a hash reference) and not a hash. Try

```
english => \%english,
spanish => \%spanish,
```

or

```
english => { %english },
spanish => { %spanish },
```

instead.

Comment: As a note - the first solution (`\%`) - stores the references to EXISTING hashes. The second ( `{%}`) - stores the references to new cloned hashes (cloning only the first level, not deep-nested cloning all structures)

Comment: Thanks.  It's my first day of Perl - man this is a weird language.

Comment: @AdamS All (programming) languages are weird. Some are just weirder than others.